# c++ network/socket programming

Tags: c++, linux, network-programming

I have been searching around the internet in order to find a tutorial on C++ socket programming. I have found some of these, but none of them really helped me making a server I could use.

I wish to make a server in C++ that can send and receive *packets*, but all the tutorials/examples I can find are about sending/receiving *strings*.

I have an average experience in C++. I am using a computer with Ubuntu (Linux).

If someone could explain me how I could make a server that sends/receives *packages* instead of strings, or points me to a good tutorial explaining me how, preferably by using the POSIX-api, it would be really great and help me a lot.

-ojima

*EDIT*

(I apparently said 'packages', but I meant 'packets')

So, let's say I want to take a Java game, say MineCraft, and write a server of it in C++. According to the MinecraftCoalition, the (Java) client send 'packets' containing data.
I wonder, how do I receive (or interpret) these packets?

[MineCraft Coalition reference](http://www.wiki.vg/Protocol)

Comment: So, in your mind, what is the difference between a packet and a string? [By the way, sending packets as strings is a pretty good idea unless you know for sure what is going to receive your packet, since you have to worry about byte order and all manner of other things if it's "some random equipemnt"]

Comment: What are you calling a package?  Something like an rpm or a deb?

Comment: In my mind, the difference is (simple said) this: a string is a series of bytes (characters), and a package is a set of values.

Comment: I think this has gone from difficult to answer to very complicated to answer. No one is going to tell you all the steps you need to send, recieve and interpret a "minecraft packet".

Comment: I think you are confused about terminology. TCP sockets operate on streams of data, not packages or packets. The stream can be binary, or some other format as described in the protocol you choose.

Comment: You should read http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/ to understand low level programming (and linux syscalls).

Answer (score 2):

If by *package* you're talking about a block of binary data then it's pretty straightforward to do but you have to be aware of the [endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) of the architecture on which you are sending - which might not be the same as the receiver which could mean that data is not reconstructed correctly.

You might be better off looking at something like [Boost.Asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html) which will take this in it's stride and is specifically tailored to C++.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to send raw data (an array of char), the difference is subtle with C string (you have to remember the terminating '\0'). That's why most documentation won't really make a difference.

My advice would be to :

1. Choose a way to convert you data to a binary format (boost::serialize, protocol buffers are decent choices but not the only one).
2. Choose some abstraction library like boost.Asio or maybe even zmq (again there are other choices).

I'm not convinced (but it's a personal opinion, probably not shared) that working on raw sockets is needed for most use cases, and some C++ abstraction is always pleasant.

Answer (score 0):

The sockets will send and receive only arrays on bytes. Conversion to string is easy so is it often taken as example. It is up to you to convert these arrays of bytes into whatever your packages are.

Answer (score 0):

Try http://www.linuxhowtos.org/C_C++/socket.htm for a basic client-server tutorial.

Comment: this isn't really an answer, please summarize your link to prevent link-rot